# Thread in background C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to show progressbar during my program is running some function. This function is running when the user click button1. I used tread which is running in background, but in my program this thread is running after program finish running this function. How can i repair it?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pr(sender,e);
}

public void pr(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (... == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (...)
        {
            Thread wa = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.lad));
            wa.IsBackground = true;

            timer1.Interval = 500;
            timer1.Start();
            wa.Start();

            if (... == DialogResult.OK)
            {//the rest of the function}
        }
    }
}

private void lad()
{
    int war = 10;

    if (this.progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        progressBar1.Invoke((Del)delegate
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++)
            {
                this.progressBar1.Value = this.progressBar1.Value + war;
            }
        });
    }
    if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("files saved");
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ladowanie_paska();
}
```

Comment: I assume these variable and function names mean....something?  Hope nobody else has to maintain this.

Comment: @Wonko Agreed, they are not intuitive.  Let's hope they are obfuscated for the purpose of online posting.

Answer (score 7):

I highly recommend rewriting the code to use the BackgroundWorker class;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

This will make it easier to update your user interface using the ProgressChanged event

Comment: This is a great start, but I sometimes make my own class similar to a backgorundworker, but declare my own event and event args classes so that the event argument can have a strongly typed progress class.

Comment: @AaronLS good advice, I also do the same and then create lots of instances of that class which self dispose when the thread is complete.

Answer (score 0):

another way is, use the delegates and multicast the same delegate which is running your porcess with the progress baar function.
something same kind of functionality is there in below code.

```
 private void BtnWatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tickerDelegate1 = new TickerDelegate(SetLeftTicker);
        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DigitalTimer));
        th.IsBackground = true;
        th.Start();

    }
    private void SetLeftTicker()
    {

        label2.Text=DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }


    public void DigitalTimer()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            label2.BeginInvoke(tickerDelegate1, new object[] {});
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

    }

    private void BtnProgrss_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // progressBar1.Visible = true;

        if (_flag == true)
        {
            tickerDelegate1 += new TickerDelegate(AnimateProgBar);
            _flag = false;
        }
    }

    private void AnimateProgBar()
    {

       num += 5;
        if (num >= 100)
        {
            num = 0;
        }
        progressBar1.Value = num;
    }

    private void SetProgressBar()
    {

        while (true)
        {

            progressBar1.Invoke(tickerDelegate1, new object[] { });
            //Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```